# MongoDB - Como filtrar documentos por palavras chaves?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Opa!
Então, como faço pra filtrar todos os documentos de um coleção, onde no campo "name" tenha uma determinada string/palavra?

Por exemplo: Eu tenho um coleção chamada Pessoas e dentro dela várias pessoas cadastradas.
-Maria Santos
-João Santos
-Maria Silva
Como eu faria pra retornar todas as pessoas que tenham "Santos" no nome?

Eu já tentei com:
*db.pessoas.find({name:"Santos"})*
*db.pessoas.find({name:{$in:"Santos"}})* e não foi.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é utilizar o find combinado com o operador `$regex`.

Segue a [documentação relacionada](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/regex/#std-label-regex-ref)

Um exemplo de caso de uso:

```
db.pessoas.find({name: {$regex: "Santos"}})
```

Se quiser uma versão não-sensível ao caso [***ignore case***, ***case insensitive***], poderia tentar:

```
db.pessoas.find({name: {$regex: /santos/i}})
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda, Dani!
Resolvido!